# Run a command in a new cmd and save the return into a file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a command-line programm that returns values. Like example this simple batch-file:

`echo "Hello World"`

In a normal situation I can pipe the output to a file like this:

`$ my_batch.bat > file.log`

The Problem occures if I want to start this in a new console with a specific title:

`$ start "NewConsole" cmd.exe /c my_batch.bat > file.log`

In this case my batch seems to run, but my file.log will be empty.

Comment: I think you have to escape the `>` like `^>` in order for it not to be consumed by the current `cmd.exe` instance. *N. B.:* `>` is not a pipe but output redirection; a pipe is `|`...

Comment: Currently you're outputting the output from `start` to the log file, and that has no output, hence the empty file. You should ensure that the output is from the `cmd.exe` command instead, which means you should keep them together. You can do that using doublequotes, like this: `Start "NewConsole" cmd.exe /C "my_batch.bat > file.log"`, or just in case of spaces in names the more robust `Start "NewConsole" cmd.exe /C ""my_batch.bat" > "file.log""`.

Comment: I would separate the part of the things that you are starting in quotes or other similar keys like parenthesis like @Compo said. So in all you would write `start "NewConsole" cmd.exe /c "('my_batch.bat > file.log')"` where you could use any grouping bracket instead of  `"('')"`

Comment: @NekoMusume, that will not work, because single quotes are just standard characters to `cmd.exe`, so they'll be treated as such! `cmd.exe` will not find a script named `'my_batch.bat` and would create an empty `file.log'` file.

Comment: I see, thank you for correcting me @Compo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Compo and @aschipfl said, the `>` in your script right now is piping the output of the whole `start` command (which is nothing) and piping your current script. However, if you either 1. break the `>` out with `^`, the `>` will pass to the next command prompt, or if you 2. put `"` around the part of your start command that passes stuff to do to the next command prompt so it passes the things you want to pass including the `>` pipe.

---

Overall you could either use this:

```
start "NewConsole" cmd.exe /c my_batch.bat ^> file.log
```

or this:

```
start "NewConsole" cmd.exe /c "my_batch.bat > file.log"
```

Comment: That was absolutly what I was looking for